# loading Rmpi with openmpi 3.0.0 on Ubuntu throwing error

Tags: r, linux, openmpi, parallel.foreach

I've got some sore of a library problem when trying to install Rmpi, having installed openmpi 3.0.0 from source to /usr/local on Ubuntu 16.04.

open mpi seems to be installed correctly, `mpirun` --version works

When I try to install Rmpi using this command

```
sudo R CMD INSTALL ./Downloads/Rmpi_0.6-6.tar.gz --configure-args="--with-Rmpi-type={OPENMPI}"
```

It compiles fine, and finds the libraries

```
I am here /usr/local and it is OpenMPI
Trying to find mpi.h ...
Found in /usr/local/include
Trying to find libmpi.so or libmpich.a ...
Found libmpi in /usr/local/lib
checking for orted... yes
checking for openpty in -lutil... yes
checking for main in -lpthread... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
```

but when it does the load test I get

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** An error occurred in MPI_Init
*** on a NULL communicator
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
***    and potentially your MPI job)
```

I've tried many things but still no luck.  How can I track down the error in the connection to mpi?

Comment: can you run a simple mpi helloworld program ? there is one in Open MPI `examples/hello_c.c`

Comment: Thx Gilles, I found it but don't know how to run it.  Suggestion?

Comment: `mpicc hello_c.c; mpirun ./a.out`

Comment: Don't think its happy, getting this [JAM-Home-PC:43694] mca_base_component_repository_open: unable to open mca_mpool_grdma: /usr/local/lib/openmpi/mca_mpool_grdma.so: undefined symbol: mca_mpool_base_page_size (ignored)   Looking in /usr/local/lib/openmpi, it appears I have some old files hanging around from a previous version of open-mpi, thought I had removed all of them.

Comment: your Open MPI install looks busted, first `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/openmpi; make install` and try again, that could be some components from a previous install

Comment: That seemed to work, mpicc hello_c.c; mpirun ./a.out 
Hello, world, I am 1 of 6, (Open MPI v3.0.0, package: Open MPI jamaas@JAM-Home-PC Distribution, ident: 3.0.0, repo rev: v3.0.0, Sep 12, 2017, 113)
Hello, world, I am 3 of 6, (Open MPI v3.0.0, package: Open MPI jamaas@JAM-Home-PC Distribution, ident: 3.0.0, repo rev: v3.0.0, Sep 12, 2017, 113) ........
I still can't load/run Rmpi though

Comment: could be a dlopen related issue. you might try reconfiguring Open MPI with `--disable-dlopen` and re-install.

Comment: That worked, steps were 1. go back to source directory and run "sudo make uninstall", 2.  run " ./configure --disable-dlopen" , 3. "make". 4. "sudo make install". 5. run "sudo ldconfig" . and then it seemed to install and run fine!

Comment: thanks for the feedback ! i will try see what exactly is going wrong. fwiw `mpi4py` dlopen Open MPI and it works just fine without the `--disable-dlopen` configure parameter. meanwhile, and for future readers, i summarized the solution/workaround and posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the various exchanges in the comment section, it appears there is an issue when Open MPI is used as a plugin by Rmpi.

The solution/workaround was to rebuild Open MPI from scratch and configure with the `--disable-dlopen` parameter.

This might be related to the issue discussed in [Open MPI](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/3705)

Answer (score 0):

If someone still have similar problem to install Rmpi (*undefined symbol: mpi_universe_size*):
with R 3.5.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 installing *libopenmpi-dev* has fixed that issue.